# The constructor HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(CloseableHttpClient) is undefined

Tags: java, spring-boot

**could you please help me to fix this issue**

I am facing issue here
[image]

Please find completed class and all imports.And kinldy help me to fix this issue.

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

    
import com.hp.it.psoit.asynmctlr.utill.Constants;

@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
        return new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {

        return new RestTemplateBuilder();
    }

    @Bean("restTemplate")
    public RestTemplate restTemplateWithTrustStoretim(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder, SSLContext sslContext) {

        return restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(() -> {
             CloseableHttpClient client =
              HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(getRequestConfig())
              .setSSLContext(sslContext).build();

            return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
        }).build();
    }

    public RequestConfig getRequestConfig() {
        int connTimeout = Constants.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
        int sktTimeout = Constants.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;

        return RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(connTimeout)
                // .setConnectionRequestTimeout(100)
                .setSocketTimeout(sktTimeout).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace and the relvant imports

Comment: So which bit is undefined?

Comment: please find i have added all the import and a snapshot

Comment: You use the wrong HTTP client.  the constructor expect `org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient`

Comment: Is this the correct dependency <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.4</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.client5/httpclient5 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Now i am getting,Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient to org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient  for   this line    :::  CloseableHttpClient client =
     HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(getRequestConfig())
     .setSSLContext(sslContext).build();

Comment: After added maven dependency should be change the import statement
to org.apache.hc.client5

Not
org.apache.http.clien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Change import statements from

```
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
```

To

```
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.io.HttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
```

**Code:**

```
SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadKeyMaterial(urlKeystore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray(),
   keyStorePassword.toCharArray()).loadTrustMaterial(urlTruststore, trustStorePassword.toCharArray()).build();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory =  new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

HttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
        .build();

org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient c5  = HttpClients.custom()
.setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
.evictExpiredConnections()
.build();

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(c5);
```